# Fetching data with axios in a custom react hook doesn't return data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I used this code to show the `id` of a product.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = "https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products";

const useGetProduct = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [singleProduct, setSingleProduct] = useState(null);
    
  const getTopProducts = () => {
    axios.get(`${BASE_URL}.json`, {
      params: {
        product_tags: 'Canadian',
      },
    })
      .then(Response => setProducts(Response.data));
  };

  const getSingleProduct = () => {
    axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/1048.jason`)
      .then(Response => setSingleProduct(Response.data));
  };

  return {
    products,
    getTopProducts,
    singleProduct,
    getSingleProduct,
  }
};

export default useGetProduct;
```

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useGetProduct from "../hooks/useGetProduct";

const Product = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { singleProduct, getSingleProduct } = useGetProduct();

  useEffect(() => {
    getSingleProduct();
  }, []);
   
  return ( 
    <div>
      <p>Product: {id}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
 
export default Product;
```

app.js

```
<Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<Product />} />
```

But when I change `<p>Product: {id}</p>` to `<p>Product: {singleProduct?.name}</p>` the product name does not display. Instead, it just shows `Product:`  without the details about the product on localhost and I am not sure why.

```
const Product = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { singleProduct, getSingleProduct } = useGetProduct();
    
  useEffect(() => {
    getSingleProduct();
  }, []);
   
  return ( 
    <div>
      <p>Product: {singleProduct?.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
 
export default Product;
```

I want to show details about a single product via a hook in react js.

Comment: The URL `axios.get(\`${BASE_URL}/1048.jason\`)` is suspicious since `json` is the usual file extension for JSON, and not `jason`. Did you mean `1048.json` instead of `1048.jason`? Additionally, check the network pane in your browser developer tools. Was the request to get the product data successful or is there a HTTP error?

Answer (score 1):

```
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { singleProduct, getSingleProduct } = useGetProduct();

  useEffect(() => {
      getSingleProduct();
  }, []);
```

You are not using the `id` from `useParams`. Shouldn't you pass it to `getSingleProduct`, I assume that `singleProduct` is undefined.

Comment: Does the `id` route path param ***need*** to be used? It is used in OP's code, it's rendered to the DOM. `getSingleProduct` doesn't consume any arguments, so it doesn't appear anything needs to be passed to it.

Comment: My assumption was that each ` path="/product/:id"` should fetch a different product and the `id`  should be passed to `getSingleProduct()` . I saw that he hardcoded the resource in `axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/1048.jason`)`, maybe just to test the api calls. Anyway I suppose that `1048.jason` throws an error and `singleProduct` is null.